# AngularJS component: using binding object in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I use Angular component (first example from [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)). When I binding object in component, it is accessible in template, but isn't in controller.

js:

```
function HeroDetailController() {
  console.log("Here I want to use hero.name: ");
  console.log(hero.name); // I want to use binding object in controller, but doesn't work
}

angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  controller: HeroDetailController,
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  bindings: {
    hero: '='
  }
});
```

html:

```
<hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
```

template html (here it works):

```
<span>Name: {{ctrl.hero.name}}</span>
```

Error:

> ReferenceError: hero is not defined

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/U9CJLs6jgrlsZH6tUdr0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will get `bindings` value inside `HeroDetailController` context which is `this`

```
function HeroDetailController() {
  var ctrl = this;
  console.log("Here I want to use hero.name: ");
  console.log(ctrl.hero);
}
```

Though above would not work. Because it would not pass initial binding to component on 1st digest cycle.

For getting the value you could use `$onInit` lifecycle value on component.

```
function HeroDetailController() {
  var ctrl = this;
  console.log("Here I want to use hero.name: ");
  ctrl.$onInit = function(){
    console.log(ctrl.hero);
  }
}
```

---

Even you could get a value directly without `$onInit`. For the same you have to change `$compileProvider` config like below.(it has been introduced in 1.6+)

```
.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)
});
```

**Note:** Ideally you shouldn't enforce above setting in your application, I just gave it fore demonstration.

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RosepbGUe9siTf7M5OHi?p=preview)