# angularJS ES6 Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I am trying to develop an application in angular es6 . I have a problem with directve.
Here is my code

```
export default class RoleDirective {
  constructor() {
    this.template="";
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.scope = {
        role :"@rolePermission"
    };

    this.controller = RoleDirectiveController;
    this.controllerAs = 'ctrl';
    this.bindToController = true;
  }

  // Directive compile function
  compile(element,attrs,ctrl) {
        console.log("df",this)
  }

  // Directive link function
  link(scope,element,attrs,ctrl) {

        console.log("dsf",ctrl.role)
  }
}

// Directive's controller
class RoleDirectiveController {
  constructor () {
    console.log(this.role)
    //console.log("role", commonService.userModule().getUserPermission("change_corsmodel"));
    //$($element[0]).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }

}

export default angular
  .module('common.directive', [])
  .directive('rolePermission',[() => new RoleDirective()]);
```

The problem is i couldn't get the role value inside constructor.
here is my html implementation

```
<a ui-sref="event" class="button text-uppercase button-md" role-permission="dfsd" detail="sdfdsfsfdssd">Create event</a>
```

If i console this it will get the controller object. But it will not get any result while use this.role.

Comment: You could refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41524591/2435473) as well.

Comment: You would have the exact same problem using ES5. And it doesn't make sense for this directive to have a controller and an isolated scope in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to find out how this works.

Basically, the scope values cannot be initialized on the controller's constructor (because this is the first thing executed on a new object) and there is also binding to be considered.

There is a hook that you can implement in your controller that can help you with your use case: `$onInit`:

```
class RoleDirectiveController {
  constructor () { 
    // data not available yet on 'this' - they couldn't be
  }

  $onInit() {
    console.log(this.role)
  }
}
```

This should work. Note that this is angular1.5+ way of doing things when not relying on $scope to hold the model anymore. Because if you use the scope, you could have it in the controller's constructor (injected).

Comment: Thanks you saved my day.. Actually i am using bindtocontroller, so its had it's own scope right? not the global scope.

Comment: You are using isolated scope (defined by using an object in your directive `scope` definition). `bindToController` is something else - this basically tells angular to use the controller object instead of the $scope object - but it would have been isolated either way