# AngularJS: ES6 $onInit and $onDestroy doesn't fire

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, angularjs-controller

I am currently develop a application with angular1.6. The modules where loaded with oclazyloading and webpack. My controller is like

```
'use strict';
class ActivityController {
    constructor($stateParams, commonService) {

        var vm = this;
        this.commonService = commonService;
    }
    $onInit() {
         console.log("on init...");
         alert();
    }
    $onDestroy() {
        console.log("destroying NewPost...");
    }
}

export default angular
    .module('activity.controller', [])
    .controller('ActivityController', ['$stateParams', 'commonService', ActivityController]);
```

When i used with directive it worked. I posted that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563351/angularjs-es6-directive?noredirect=1#comment70334605_41563351).

Comment: Is the controller instantiated by a router? `$onInit` is only invoked, if the controller is part of a directive. We need information about how the controller is used.

Comment: Yes the controller is instantiated by the router , not by the directive. I think that's causes the problem.