# Why is binding value not available in controller immediately in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind some values in an angular 1.6 component that should be available to the controller code.

I must be misunderstanding it, but the variables aren't available when the controller runs. The only way I've managed it is by putting a $timeout in to push the code into the next digest cycle.

What am I doing wrong here?

The relevant section is here:

```
var SelectorCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
  function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var self = this;
    alert("1: " + self.hierarchyId);

    // I'm not 100% sure why this has to be in the next digest cycle
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.categories = self.categories;
      alert("2: " + self.hierarchyId);

    });
}

app.component('categorySelector', {
  templateUrl: 'categorySelector.html',
  controller: SelectorCtrl,
  bindings: {
    hierarchyId: "@",
    disabled: "=",
    categories: "=",
    onSelectionChanged: "&"
  }
});
```

See plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8rtDuCawdHaiXzQU5VBR

Comment: why are you mixing `$scope` and `this` in the same component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(flag)` introduced in Angular 1.6, you can configure it on config cycle on `$compileProvider`

> If disabled (false), the compiler calls the constructor first before
>   assigning bindings.
>
> The default value is true in Angular 1.5.x but will switch to false in
>   Angular 1.6.x.

You will get all bindings inside `$onInit` lifecycle event of Angular component, where all the bindings would be available(if binding passed synchronously).

```
self.$onInit = function() {
  $scope.categories = self.categories;
  alert("2: " + self.hierarchyId);
};
```

> **Note:** It's bad practice to mix `$scope` with `this`. Rather avoid using `$scope` to make your code Angular 2 migration proof.

---

If you want binding to be available when controller function instantiate then you could set `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)`. Which will make `self.categories`(bindings) value.

```js
app.config(function($compileProvider){
   $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)
});
```

[**Similar answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524591/2435473)

---

### Angular 1.7.x update

As of Angular 1.7.x, the `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(flag)` is gone, and it is no longer possible to assign bindings before the constructor.

To work around this, you need to define a `link` function in your directive definition. You can make this function call a method on your controller like this:

```js
app.directive("directive", function() {
  return {
    controller: DirectiveController, // bind controller any way you want
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    bindToController: true,
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.ctrl.init(); // this will call an init() function on your controller
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, no worries will stick with `$onInit`. It's not shown here, but I'm using Devextreme UI library (angular 1 integration) which looks in scope for it's values - so need to pass a string to their components, which is the name of the scope variable. So values need to be set into scope. Cheers.

Comment: @RichardG you don't need to use `$scope` at all, you can pass binding to devexpress control like `$ctrl.categories`(which internally present in scope variable only). I'm using `devexpress` with `controllerAs` pattern. it works well :)